# Turning an xml feed and its data into an working variables and arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, simplexml

Ive got an xml feed of data, about sports events there are multiple events in the feed, and multiple attributes containing information for each event.

the feed im using is - http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=5&marketSort=HH&filterBIR=N

I want to be able to build a page using this information, so i though the first step would be to turn each event into a an array and then have nested arrays in that with the information.

Something like this :

```
$events = array();
    $event[101] => array(
    "id" => "Logo Shirt, Red",
    "name" => "img/shirts/shirt-101.jpg",
    "url" => 18,
    "date" => "2013-03-17",
    "time" => "09:00:00",
    "participant[101]" => array(
        "name" => "Mark Webber",
        "id"212770049",
        "odds" => "4/1",
        "oddsDecimal" => "5.00"
         );
     "participant[102]" => array(
        "name" => "Sebastian Vettel",
        "id"212770048",
        "odds" => "1/7",
        "oddsDecimal" => "1.14"
         );
    );
```

then go onto the next event and have that listed as `$event[102]`

How can i convert the data into a set of working variables like this ?

Also is this the best way to get the data i need from the xml feed to work with or would i be better pulling it from the feed as and when i needed a particular piece of data (although i presume that would need to call the feed each time) ? If so what would be the sytnax for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://php.net/simplexml to parse XML file. If you are calling the feed on each request it will slow down the page, you can cache the feed lcoaly as XML file and parse that file.

You can set up a CRON job to update the cache file periodically according to your needs.

Comment: im already pulling in the feed using      $xml = simplexml_load_file('f1_feed.xml'); saved localy for development, is it prefrable to get the information straight from there, rather than storing it all to a bunch of working variables and arrays ?